# Make a UITextView object editable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

This is obviously an extremely "noobish" question.  I'm aware that `UITextView` has a `Boolean` `editable` property, (since [I'm not entirely illiterate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITextView)) so the answer to my question seems really straightforward.  But...

I create a UITextView programatically like this:

```
UITextView* input = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
input.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
input.editable = YES;
input.text = @"Type something here...";
[input setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];

....

[mainView addSubview: input];
```

But when I run the iPhone simulator with Xcode, clicking on the input field doesn't do anything.  I can't input any text, the virtual keyboard doesn't appear, etc.

So, what am I doing wrong here?  Why isn't the `UITextView` object actually editable in the Xcode iPhone emulator?

Comment: Do you see the default text?

Comment: That is very odd... You see the text and the white background?

Comment: Yes I see the default text

Comment: Is mainView.userInteractionEnabled?

Comment: Where are you adding the UITextView?  ViewDidLoad?

Comment: check textview base view frame,if textview out of bounds in base view it not detect user interactions in view

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code in the viewDidLoad command of a sample app that I test code in and it works fine. In my case, I have a UIWebView that I added via Interface Builder which your UITextView pops on top of. I click it and the keyboard pops up.

Is it possible that you may be creating some other object that is begin added to the view after your textfield that is covering it up? Any other view objects being added in the `....` part of your sample code?